# Organizing C++, Java and Python Codebases in a GIT Repository

Tags: version-control

I am reorganizing 3 different implementations of a library in Java (built with Maven), C++ built with CMake and Python in a Git repository. One simplistic way is to simply have 3 top level directories Java, C++ and Python and put all code underneath it. An alternative is to use the Maven directory structure, that is, put Java code under src/main/java, c++ code under src/main/cpp, Python code under src/main/python. Similarly for tests (src/test/java etc.).

Are there any recommendations on how this should be done? Ideally, if you could point me to some open source project with Java, C++ and Python code, I could study how their codebase is organized. What would be good candidates?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to go with the latter case, the Maven directory structure. It is not only a Java Maven specific conventions. Hence, other programming languages will fit good into that structure, for instance:

```
src/main/cpp
src/main/python
src/main/groovy
...
```

For some you will even find corresponding Maven plugins. Anyway, there are *no recommendations* per ses, but it is heavily used that way.

Please also see the answers to the following question which were also answered with respect to other languages than Java: [Java project directory structure convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10590366/java-project-directory-structure-convention)

I also have projects which contain multiple codes, both each of them belong to different components, for instance:

- Client written in Java
- Server written in Python

Then I create folders for each component since it does not belong together as the other project structure would imply.