# Java project directory structure convention

Tags: java, maven, directory

I have worked on maven projects in which the directory structure looks like:

```
src/
  main/
    java/
  test/
    java/
```

I was wondering if other directory structure conventions exists.  Is this convention maven-specific or is it applicable to all of Java?  I have a project that requires multiple programming languages and was curious about whether some standard exists.

Comment: Yes, it's Maven-specific.  It can be adopted by non-Maven Java projects, but that was the origin.

Comment: Yes also there is `src/main/resources`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is Maven-specific convention of directory structure, however it's become quite popular even outside the Maven world, since it is good (like any other convention that makes sense) and there is no reason why not use it with Ant-managed project or just regular Java project. Even Java nature of the project is not needed. For example, there is [FlexMojos](http://flexmojos.sonatype.org/) project that enables Flex projects to be managed by Maven.

If you plan to use many programming languages, you have to use some additional plugins that extend Maven capabilities. For example, you can use [GMaven](http://groovy.codehaus.org/GMaven) plugin to enable Groovy language support in Maven project. Then, there is convention (in fact: default setting of plugin) to put Groovy sources into `src/main/groovy`. By default, only Java is supported.

Answer (score 3):

The convention is to follow the [default folder layout in Maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html). Furthermore other programming language follow those conventions like src/main/c++ etc.