# Why is there a "test" and and a "main" folder when it comes to Java?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I was writing my program in a specific class in the `test` folder (created automaticaly by intellij) and was running it as was. Then I needed to run my Java program from a shell and I realized that I needed to write my program in a `main` class.

So now I wonder what is the easiest way for me to run my already written code from a `main` class and if the folders `Test` and `Main` have a role in it?

Comment: [Related reading.](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java project directory structure convention](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10590366/java-project-directory-structure-convention)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a property of Java, but a convention of test driven development. The 'Test' folder is meant to store code that tests your 'Main' code. So, for example, a class called Foo with a method called bar() would exist in a package under the 'main' folder. The corresponding test, which confirms that Foo.bar() functions as expected would be under the 'test' folder.

IntelliJ understands this convention, and will let you run your test code from within the 'test' folder, and let you run application code from within the 'main' folder.

Answer (score 0):

Those folders aren't a part of Java per se and have nothing to do with the `main` method. They're used to separate the code and resources which will be packaged up and deployed from those that are there to run automated tests on the main code but aren't delivered in the binary package.

I don't use IntelliJ, but in Eclipse, I can just right-click on a class with a `main` method and run it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a convention that came from building tools, especially maven. The idea is to seperate code & resources that are needed for the actual run of the program from code & resources that are only for tests.

Answer (score 0):

it is a convention to use a main and test folders. to separate different functionality. the main folder's purpose is for the whole application whereas the test folder's purpose is for the unit testing, integration testing, etc... actually there is another folder which is resource where you put your xml, properties files and etc while main folder contains the `.java` files.